# Products are disappeared on the frontend. All show up after reindex manually. - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, products, magento2.4.2

All products are disappeared on the frontend. All show up again after reindex all

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After a few hours later, all products are disappeared again on categories and search results.

I did 'bin/magento cron:install'

It looks cronjob is working

[image]

Magento 2.4.2

Comment: where you face this issue in local system or live server?

Comment: I can confirm this issue, seeing the exact same thing after upgrading from 2.4.1 to 2.4.2.

Comment: @yohan have you faced this issue in your local setup?

Comment: @ZealousWeb On live server. Could you help?

Comment: @Alldo I have same issues in the previous version too 2.4.0 ~ 2.4.1. Have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by increasing the PHP memory limit (`memory_limit`) in both your `.user.ini` files and `php.ini` to `2048M`(`memory_limit = 2048M`).

Comment: I will test. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**you can set cron job for reindexing**

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/user/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log
```